# what is and how can i calculate this congruence? $5^{625} \equiv x \pmod{41}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$$5^{625} \equiv x \pmod{41}$$

I know that it is like $41 \mid 5^{625}-x$, but I don't know how to continue with that or how can I try it

Comment: $5^{625}\equiv5^{25}\bmod41$ (cf. [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem))

Comment: but how can I calculate that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$5^{625}\equiv5^{25}\bmod41$ by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

$5^3\equiv2\bmod 41$ and $2^7\equiv5\bmod 41$.

Therefore, $5^{25}\equiv2^85\equiv50\equiv9\bmod 41$.